# Startup Script on Windows GCE - Where is it logged?

Tags: windows, startup, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm wondering where startup script logging occurs (if it does automatically) on the MS Windows Images provided by Google for the GCE.  The documentation is pretty clear about logging for the Linux images, but doesn't indicate anything for Windows.

Thanks in advance!

-Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a practical test, here is what I can say

-GCE stores the script in the following location

C:\Program Files\Google\Compute Engine\sysprep\startup_script.ps1

-The script is executed using a task in the Task Scheduler, root folder, named:  GCEStartup

-The script is passed as a command-line parameter to powershell.exe, meaning there is no automatic logging.

Answer:  You need to implement logging in your script manually.  The only output is the basic Task Scheduler logs.

Answer (score 2):

There still doesn't seem to be an official log location for these startup scripts. I solved this problem by wrapping my script in a stdin/err redirect:

```bsh
& {
# Lines of code here
echo "doing things"
} *> C:\gce-startup.log
```

`*>` redirects all output.

`1> C:\gce-stdout.log` for just stdout

`2> C:\gce-stderr.log` for just stdeer

`1> C:\gce-stdout.log 2> C:\gce-stderr.log` for both but separated.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation on startup scripts for Windows](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems#using_startup_scripts_on_windows) does not mention a specific location or file for these logs as there isn't one. Windows handles all of this differently than Linux and as such, there is no equivalent of the `/var/log/startupscript.log` file.

Your best bet would be to go through the System and Application logs in the Event Viewer. This is just how Windows works.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping for some official documentation.  I'll spin up an instance tonight and see if I can find the logging for a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 30 -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Application';ProviderName='GCEMetaDataScripts'} | ft -Wrap -AutoSize
```

This will show you the errors. GCP helpfully logs to the Windows Application log.